# Excel Dropdown - Data validation only list col1 entries where col2 value = x

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook with multiple sheets.
i have a dropdown on sheet 1 that retrieves a list of values from sheet 2 as a data validation by list.
on sheet 2, there are entries in col1 and col2... col1 is what appears in the sheet 1 dropdown.
in the dropdown, i only want the entries from sheet 2, col1 where col2 in the same row as col1 ="Y"

basically my dropdown is supposed to show the values marked as active on the second sheet

i'm digging around for how to do this... as i'm almost certain i've done exactly this before.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a "lazy" answer - but you can find a full (very detailed) walkthrough for your requirement afai understood it,  here: https://www.contextures.com/exceldropdownfilteredlist.html

Comment: first.. thank you.   second... damn that's a lot of stuff  for what i thought would be simple